# getting problem performing a post request to an external API

Tags: node.js, api, post, axios

I'm using axios to perform get and post requests to an external api,
i have finally succeed to achieve get request (problem with the ssl certificate, i avoid it by adding this : 
httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false }),

now i would like to post the api,

to get the request working in postman, i put in 
headers content-type : application/json 
and in the body : {}

[like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nT1O.jpg)

when trying with a google chrome extention, to make it work, i put nothing in the headers but in params, i select customer : application/json and i put inside this {} instead of the default choice which is x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

[chrome extention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRlCY.jpg)

in my javascript app i tried this

var url = `https://10.11.31.100:9440/api/nutanix/v3/images/list`;

```
axios({
    method:'post',
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false }),
    url,
    auth: {
        username: '******',
        password: '********'
    },
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
params: {},
    data: {}

})
.then(function (response) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

I get this problem :

TypeError : UTF-8 is not a function

Comment: The `TypeError : UTF-8 is not a function` is printed by the `.catch()`? What's the point of the `X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest` header? This code seems ok to me.

Comment: yes the error is hadled by the catch promise

Comment: 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' has no point i just tried it

Comment: don't you think there is a problem with axios supporting node.js post requests ?

Comment: I don't think the problem is on axios itself. Seems that somewhere you're trying to use a string like a function: `const randomName = 'foobar'` => `randomName()`

Comment: see the two pictures that i just appended to the post

Comment: no effectively it's an axios issue with post requests, mine is a little special because i should ignore ssl certificate verification and there is basic auth authentification, so somewhere there is a bug 
ps: get request work fine.
finally thank's for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Specifically with regards to the Nutanix v3 REST API - this is probably because the POST request above doesn't have an appropriate JSON payload i.e. the "data" parameter is empty.

When sending Nutanix v3 API POST requests, specifically to "list" entities, you'll need to specify the "kind" of entity being listed.  In your example, the JSON payload below will work.

```
{"kind":"image"}
```

See here: https://nutanix.dev/reference/prism_central/v3/api/images/postimageslist

HTH. :)